# Grunt Watch and Connect is not working together

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, taskmanager, grunt-contrib-connect

I am trying to register a custom task that combines the connect and watch task on grunt, but it seems like it is just running the first element(task) of the array on the function grunt.registerTask. In this situation, it is just running the watch command, not the connect.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: '8000',
          protocol: 'http',
          hostname: 'localhost',
          base: 'app',
          keepalive: true,
          livereload: true,
          open: true
        }
      }
    },
    wiredep: {
      task: {
        src: ['app/index.html'],
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      },
      all: [
        'GruntFile.js',
        'app/scripts/*',
        'test/spec/*'
      ]
    },
    sass: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'app/stylesheets/main.css': 'app/sass/main.sass'
        },
        options: {
          compass: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: true
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['app/sass/*.sass'],
        tasks: ['sass'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      scripts: {
        files: ['app/scripts/*.js', 'GruntFile.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      }
    }
  });
// ========================================================

// Loading npm tasks
// ========================================================
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-wiredep');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
// ========================================================

// Register npm tasks
// ========================================================
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'wiredep', 'jshint', 'sass', 'watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('serve',['watch', 'connect:server']);
// ======================================================== 

};
```

How can I work this two tasks together with registerTask function?